# GET and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: get, xmlhttprequest

i have an XMLHttpRequest.The request passes a parameter to my php server code in /var/www. But i cannot seem to be able to extract the parameter back at the server side. below i have pasted both the codes:

javascript:

```
function getUsers(u)
{ 
 alert(u);//here u is 'http://start.ubuntu.com/9.10'
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url="http://localhost/servercode.php"+"?q="+u;

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= useHttpResponse;
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function useHttpResponse() 
{

 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 )
 {
 var response = eval('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
  for(i=0;i<response.Users.length;i++)
        alert(response.Users[i].UserId);

 }
}
```

servercode.php:

```
 <?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
//$q="http://start.ubuntu.com/9.10";
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","blaze");
if(!$con)
{die('could not connect to database'.mysql.error());
}
mysql_select_db("BLAZE",$con) or die("No such Db");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERURL WHERE URL='$q'");

 if($result == null)
 echo 'nobody online';
 else
  {
  header('Content-type: text/html');
  echo "{\"Users\":[";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo '{"UserId":"'.$row[UsrID].'"},';
  }
  echo "]}";
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

this is not giving the required result...although the commented statement , where the variable is assigned explicitly the value of the argument works...it alerts me the required output...but somehow the GET method's parameter is not reaching my php or thats how i think it is....pls help....

Comment: You should use formating for the code portion of your questions by following the conventions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Use firebug to see exactly what URL is being sent up by xmlhttprequest.  My guess is that the URL that you have as a querystring value is being URL encoded in a way that's messing you up.

Answer (score 2):

If `u` is `http://start.ubuntu.com/9.10` as you write, the URL gets garbled because `:` is a forbidden character in a URL.

You need to escape the URL using `encodeURIComponent()` in Javascript, and `urldecode()` it back in PHP. Docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) and [here](http://www.php.net/urldecode).

The JavaScript part would look like so:

```
 var url="http://localhost/servercode.php"+"?q="+encodeURIComponent(u);
```

and the PHP part:

```
 $q=urldecode($_GET["q"]);
```

your mySQL query is also vulnerable to a **SQL injection**, which is highly dangerous. You should at least sanitize `$q` using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) for an overview on the problem, and possible solutions.

Comment: i changed the statements like u said... but i still din get any output....am going through the sql injection part....but changing those 2 statements is supposed to give me the output right? – Neethusha 0 secs ago

Comment: @Neethusha you need to make test outputs of `$_GET["u"]` on PHP side and look what they contain.

Comment: Strange, I don't know. Can you try a simple value for `q`, for example "123" (instead of the complex URL)?

Comment: i tried something simple like 'hai' including entries for all that in my db....somehow unless expliciltly given value for $q, the php code does not give op...is anything else necessary for the GET XMLHttpRequest n response to work?

Comment: @ Pekka...ok..der is an improvement..my javascript file was in chrome since i was developing an extension..so i moved my js file to /var/www...and it did give op for simple parameters like 'hai' n 'php.com'....but then again wen a full url is passed, it does not give output...moreover since it is a firefox extension, my js file will have to be in the chrome folder...so is there something that i have to add to the request to make it work from the chrome folder?that is from the client side browser to the server.....

Comment: but is encodeURIComponent n escape of javascript compatible with urldecode of php?

Comment: @Neethusha you're right, it is not 100% compatible. There seems to be no function in JS that produces data that can be decoded by PHP's `urldecode()`. See for example here for an implementation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php#85903 The chrome stuff I don't know about, but maybe this sorts it out.

Comment: i got the op...its like wen u do the encodeURIComponent from javascript, it autodecodes at the php side...need not use urldecode....thank you Pekka........:-)